# Running my first program using TestNG and getting error

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, testng

I am getting following error when run my selenium webdriver progarm using testNG:

```
 org.testng.TestNGException: 
 Cannot find class in classpath: testng
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:543)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Please help how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved Error. I was missing main class of java so it was giving me error. Just added main class and then program runs successfully.

Comment: Please can you explian the solution details.I am getting the same error

Comment: I am new to Selenium. Could you please let me know what exactly did you do to resolve this. Thanks

Comment: @HelpingHands just commenting so you know there's a comment on here, since I don't know if you get pinged since I converted it from an answer. :)

Comment: @corsiKa - Okay :)

Comment: @RamDevalkar - I was missing java MAIN class and once added it , my error was resolved.